# How to keep a div in the same location in the page not depending if use Windows logo key + Left/Right arrow

Tags: css, html

When I use the keyboard shortcut to move the window the left/right side of the screen and then minimize it up/down.
Using Windows key + Left/Right arrow, then Windows key + Up/Down arrow 
OR when using the mouse by moving the cursor to any edge or corner of the window until a double-headed arrow appears and then resize it custom.

I want the div( white-container box) always to located in the centre.

First of all, I trying to create a login page the will be the same as the following picture, beside the background picture:

[image]

I'm using a screen with 1920x1080p resolution, I don't know if my work is good according to using right in `div` or in classes or how it'll work on other resolutions.

**Edit:**
**My background picture is also 1920x1080p.**

```css
body {
    background-image: url(../images/website-login-background.jpg);
    background-size: initial;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    resize: initial;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.white-container {
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left: 36%;
    /* width: max-content; */
    width: 28em;
    height: 28em;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;  
}
h1 {
    padding-top: 2em;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
 .form-menu {
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;  
 }  
.input {
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 80%;
}
.linkaAttr {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: blue;
    padding-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="white-container">
        <header>
            <h1>Log In to Your Account</h1><br>
        </header>
        <form class="form-menu" action="#">
            <input class="input" type="text" name="iD" placeholder="&emsp;Email or phone or username"><br><br>
            <input class="input" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="&emsp;Password"><br><br>
            <div class="linkaAttr">
                <a href="#">Forgot password?</a><br><br><br>
            </div>
            <input class="input" type="submit" style="background-color: rgb(30, 151, 213); color: white" value="Log In"><br><br><br>
            <p style="color: gray">Need an account?&emsp;<a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
        </form>  
    </div>
</body>
```

In the actual result, when I resize the window using the keyboard to left/right + up/down corner, I have the option to scroll the window, I don't need it, and white `div` are not fully showing and I need to scroll down to get it shown. Another problem is that the white `div` is not shown in the center when I resize like that the window.

In the expected result, I want that the white `div` will be the minimum size of the whole page, if I'll resize it using the mouse, the white `div` always will be in the center till the window size can't get smaller because it shows only the `div`.
If I'll resize the page using keyboard. then I want the `div` always fully shown and centered.

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexbox to make things simple and accurate. The code below should help you get started :)

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x400/fff000');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  resize: initial;
  font-family: Arial;
  /* Using Display Flex*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.white-container {
  width: 28em;
  height: 28em;
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.form-menu {
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 80%;
}

.linkaAttr {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: blue;
  padding-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-container">
  <header>
    <h1>Log In to Your Account</h1><br>
  </header>
  <form class="form-menu" action="#">
    <input class="input" type="text" name="iD" placeholder="&emsp;Email or phone or username"><br><br>
    <input class="input" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="&emsp;Password"><br><br>
    <div class="linkaAttr">
      <a href="#">Forgot password?</a><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <input class="input" type="submit" style="background-color: rgb(30, 151, 213); color: white" value="Log In"><br><br><br>
    <p style="color: gray">Need an account?&emsp;<a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: it works well in issue of centered `div`, it always in the center.
In the beginning I need that the `div` will be at bottom-center like in the picture.
It works well when resize the window from left/right  with the mouse but still it gives the ability resize the window from up/bottom more the `div` size and then I get the scroll bar the I don't need.

Comment: How do I disable the option to resize the window more than `div` height and `div` width?
In your answer, I still can resize the page more than `div` height until I only see the address bar and resize the width more `div` width but it stops and I can't resize it further, it shrinks the width of input and the width of `h1`.

Comment: Just play with the flex properties. You can align it the way you want. Justify-content and align-items. You have to read a little about flex, it's pretty simple and very powerful.

Comment: Search for flex playground. It's a nice tool to  understand flex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `margin:0 auto` in `white-container` to keep that `div` as center no matter what is size of your screen;

```css
body {
    background-image: url(../images/website-login-background.jpg);
    background-size: initial;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    resize: initial;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.white-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* width: max-content; */
    width: 28em;
    height: 28em;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;  
}
h1 {
    padding-top: 2em;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
 .form-menu {
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;  
 }  
.input {
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 80%;
}
.linkaAttr {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: blue;
    padding-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js_formname_formelementname.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="white-container">
        <header>
            <h1>Log In to Your Account</h1><br>
        </header>
        <form class="form-menu" action="#">
            <input class="input" type="text" name="iD" placeholder="&emsp;Email or phone or username"><br><br>
            <input class="input" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="&emsp;Password"><br><br>
            <div class="linkaAttr">
                <a href="#">Forgot password?</a><br><br><br>
            </div>
            <input class="input" type="submit" style="background-color: rgb(30, 151, 213); color: white"
                value="Log In"><br><br><br>
            <p style="color: gray">Need an account?&emsp;<a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I use `margin:0 auto`, the white `div` it positions the `div` at top-center and still when resize using the keyboard, the window has a scrolling option.
Screenshot: https://imgur.com/GhXIfMJ and still I can resize it with the mouse to width less than the `div`.

Comment: when we resize the window using `windows + arrow keys` then size of window becomes smaller then the size of `<div>`

Comment: Thanks, How do I fix it?
I need to change the size of the `div`?
How I position the `div` at the bottom?

Comment: you could change height or you could also adjust your top down margins so that 
the three inputs stay in center if size of window becomes less than size of <div>